# Save Ransack search param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I would like to display the search term a user inputs as part of the markup in the resulting page.

I was hoping the simple `<%= params[:q] %>` would do the trick, but that returns the predicate as well eg. `{"title_or_content_cont"=>"foo"}`

How can I extract just "foo"?

Comment: Did you try - `<%= params[:q]["title_or_content_cont"] %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by Kumar is good, though I'd go with a slightly different approach to cover occasions where `params[:q]` is `nil`.

Were it to be nil, the following would result in an error:

```
<%= params[:q][:title_or_content_cont] %>
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Therefore, to process this safely you should use one of the following approaches (ref for [`:dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) and [`:try`](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Object:try)):

```
<%= params.dig(:q, :title_or_content_cont) %> # on newer versions of Rails
<%= params[:q].try(:[], :title_or_content_cont) %> # on older versions
```

This is crucial - if you don't account for this, you'll get an error whenever the search term is missing.

Both of the above return nil if nothing is found, so you can leave it displaying nothing, or add alternative copy should nothing be found, i.e.

```
<%= params.dig(:q, :title_or_content_cont) || "No search term" %>
```

Hope this helps - let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: `<%= params.dig(:q, :title_or_content_cont) %>` works like a charm. Thank you for the simple and effective answer.

Answer (score 1):

`params` is an instance of class `ActionController::Parameters`. Which means you can access data from it like you would do from a ruby hash.

```
<%= params[:q][:title_or_content_cont] %> #returns the value foo

# You can also use keys wrapped with quotes

<%= params[:q]["title_or_content_cont"] %> #returns the value foo
```

So if you have a nested hash, you can keep looking of keys in the similar way.